# Sphinx "nosearch" option not working as intended

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am looking to exclude a particular RST file from the search index.
I have found the `nosearch` field that should do exactly that.
The file looks like this:

```
:nosearch:

.. currentmodule:: interactions

HTTP
====

.. autoclass:: interactions.api.http.member.MemberRequest
   :members:
```

However, if I try to lookup a method from the MemberRequest class, it will still show it in the search index, although it should not.
I would gladly appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The [:nosearch:](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/field-lists.html#special-metadata-fields) option only disables full-text search (meaning prose), not object search (meaning Python, C++, etc... objects) - see the note at the bottom of the linked page. If you want to disable search for objects too add the [:noindex:](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#basic-markup) flag under the autoclass directive.

Comment: Thank you, I had not understood the difference between full-text and object search.